# Where do I place a C library for use on Windows, Mac, and Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, package

I have looked at a few places to figure out where to place the file on Macs, and it seems that placing them into `/usr/lib/libmylib.dylib` and `/usr/include/mylib.h` is the correct place, rather than either in the HOME directory, or in `/usr/local/lib`. (This is for something the user installs on their computer).

Please let me know if that is correct.

Then the rest of my question is where is the equivalent (i.e. *best*) place to place a C lib on windows and linux. Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230041/what-is-the-equivalent-of-usr-lib-on-windows) for windows says either `%windir%\system32` or `%SystemRoot%\winsxs`. But then they go about seemingly saying that it's still a bad place to put it for several reasons. So I'm not sure there.

Then the rest is how to do it for [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685716/where-to-put-third-party-libraries-to-setup-a-c-linux-development-environment). Seems to be the same as on Mac.

The end goal is so someone can simply do `#include <mylib.h>` in their C code and get it to work.

Comment: For Linux and Mac, see [Where do executables look for shared objects at runtime?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime).

Comment: Beware that the question on Unix Stack Exchange dates to 2011.  If there's any information related to macOS (MacOS X as it then was), it is probably no longer accurate.  The SIP feature changed the rules.

Comment: In Windows, there is no single place to place the header files. Remember that Windows is a developer-hostile environment.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which versions of macOS you're using.

For a Mac, you won't be able to place libraries in `/usr/lib` or headers in `/usr/include` under macOS since Apple added 'System Integrity Protection' (SIP) to macOS 10.11 El Capitan (circa October 2015).  You will need to use `/usr/local/lib` or maybe somewhere under `/opt`.

You then need to determine whether your C compiler is configured to look for headers in `/usr/local/include` and libraries in `/usr/local/lib` by default.  If it isn't, then you'll need to add `-I /usr/local/include` and `-L /usr/local/lib` to the command line.  (If you place your library under `/opt`, you'll definitely need comparable options with the appropriate value.)

You can find some relevant links in [Can Mac OS X El Capitan run software compiled for Yosemite that expects libraries in /usr/gnu64/lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074492/)  The answer to the headline question of that link is "No, it can't".

Answer (score 1):

@ Linux:

- /usr/lib path's for dynamic libraries (.so)
- /usr/include path's for libraries headers (.h)

/usr/local/include it's a path prefix for user programs not managed by the distribution. You will want to indicate this path to C compiler in order to find  libraries. Your command it's like this:

```
gcc -o <src_program_app> -I/usr/local/include/<ur_library_dir> <src_program>.c
```

Where src_program.c has the import of library found on ur_library_dir.

However, you can later go try a Build System like Cmake which automates this compiling.