# Into which folders are things typically installed on Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895536/where-do-i-place-a-c-library-for-use-on-windows-mac-and-linux) question early about storing C files on all different platforms, but for this question I would like to focus only on Windows because I haven't found any good resources on it yet.

Basically, where are these things *generally* or *typically* stored on windows:

- C libs
- Database files
- Config files
- Log files
- Shell scripts

On mac I have this:

```
/usr/local/lib/libfoo.dylib
/usr/local/include/foo.h
/usr/local/bin/foo
```

On linux I have this:

```
/usr/lib/libfoo.so
/usr/include/foo.h
/etc/foo
/var/lib/foo
/var/log/foo
```

But the question is for windows, for which I've pieced together this:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\stone\libfoo.a
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\stone\foo.dll
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\stone\foo.h
c:\bin\dev\foo
```

The question is if I'm on the right track for windows, and what the log and config and database spots are for windows.

For example, where does the [homebrew for windows](https://chocolatey.org/) store stuff? Maybe they have a good system. If there is no standard, that would be good to know (I assume there is no standard).

Comment: I'm somewhat confused here. If you want to know where Homebrew installs files, can't you just install Homebrew and see where the files are installed?

Comment: I'm talking about _the equivalent of_ homebrew for windows. I don't have a windows machine to test on.

Comment: Generally where the installer, application, or user chooses. Config files usually should be in AppData or registry.